# Is it possible to parse a Snakemake file?

Tags: python, snakemake

I was wondering if is possible to programmatically parse a snakemake file. Snakefiles can often contain dynamic content both from python functions as well as wildcards that need to be resolved. I was wondering if its possible to resolve this content and then query the resulting rules/targets i.e. something like this (pseudo code):

./Snakefile:

```
rule:
    input: "program.py"
    output: "output_{suffix}.out"
    shell: "python program.py --arg {wildcard.suffix}"
```

Parsing code:

```py
ps = parse_snakemake("./Snakefile", target ="output_VAR.out")
print(ps.rules[0].shell)
#> "python program.py --arg VAR"
```

Comment: You can direct the results of a dry-run to stdout and then parse that?

Comment: @Wayne , thank you for the idea, I was considering that but then free text parsing is throught with issues, was just hoping for a more integrated solution

Comment: Also, you can get all sorts of information out by throwing `print(locals())` into your snakefile and running dry-run. (I think that was the one out of `vars()`, `globals()`, and `locals()` that looked most informative.) I wasn't able to find something to 'inspect' your snakefile internals in the way you described yet. Doesn't mean it isn't out there. Hopefully someone else may chime in if there is. And so the suggestions I am proposing are meant to be useful if there isn't a pre-made solution along those lines.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `-p` argument which prints the prompts for each rule.  I usually run `-nq` to check I have the right number of jobs then `-np` to see if my commands are put together properly.